# PHP / MySQL: How to use INSERT INTO only if certain condition is met

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-into

I am new to MySQL and hope someone can help me with this.

I currently use the following as part of a longer statement in PHP in order to write something to a db table which works as intended:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO History (email, year, halfYear, language, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("siiss", $email, $year, $halfYear, $language, $content);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

**How can I check if the corresponding email address** (`$email`) **already has 3 entries in the db** and only write in the db when it has 2 or less entries (otherwise I just want to echo something) ?

I was thinking I could use something like `$result->num_rows` but wasn't sure how to apply this here.

Can someone help me with this ?

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: count in select if >= 3 - same thing applies to num_rows in a conditional statement

Comment: @Fred -ii-: ok, so I would first select all rows with that email and then use the above to count the result ?

Comment: sidenote: careful with your use of `year` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: that is exactly what I mean @keewee279 - use a conditional statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Thanks - good point, will rename that.

Comment: you're welcome. you can still use `year` just as long as you wrap it in ticks `\``

Comment: @Divyank again.. OP is using mysqli not PDO `rowCount()` is PDO.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Ok, and for the actual if would I do something like the following: if($result->num_rows == 3){ ... } ?

Comment: that `num_rows == 3` sure, or `num_rows >= 3` just in case if you want to check if more than 3 also

Comment: Ok, perfect - thanks a lot ! I want to put it in an answer I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per requested by the OP.

You first need to count the results in a SELECT all set inside a conditional statement.

If the query matches the criteria, perform the next one.

Example using num_rows:

```
if($result->num_rows == 3){ 

  // do something 
}

else { 
  // do something else 
}
```

or `num_rows >= 3` should you want to check if equal and/or more than 3 also.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Sidenote:

Be careful with your use of `year` it is a MySQL reserved keyword:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

You can still use it, but just as long as you wrap it in ticks.

I.e.:

```
(email, `year`, halfYear, language, content)
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks a lot - will accept as soon as I can ! :)